# Automate Yosemite Upgrade

Tags: macos, upgrade, install, command-line, script

I want to be able to launch the Yosemite Installer app from the Applications folder and install the upgrade with commands.

When I look inside the InstallESD.img there are many PKG files, I am unsure how to script al this.

I have a way to get the Installer app to the machine and way to launch it. Problem is navigating the options for choosing a volume to install on and the "Continue, restart and agreement" buttons that need clicking.

What automation or scripts exist to simplify this upgrade?

Answer (score 4):

After a search, the open-source munki tool has the script I need.

- https://github.com/munki/createOSXinstallPkg

This works perfectly for my needs. Also, you could do far worse than AutoDMG which does a similar task for restore based workflows.

- https://github.com/MagerValp/AutoDMG

Comment: In many ways, munki is better than the commercial MDM solutions - especially searching and reusing parts you might need.